# How can I change my pip's directory from 3.7.5 to 3.7.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip

I downloaded Python 3.7.6 manually from its site as a tar file like this:

```
tar -xvf Python-3.7.6.tar.xz
cd Python-3.7.6
./configure
make
make install
```

I just setup it in Kali Linux, i downloaded pip for Python3 with this code after it:

```
apt install python3-pip
```

I downloaded pip3 without any problems but the thing is when I try to download some pip packages with:

```
pip3 install <Package_Name>
```

I don't get any error,I can download any packages with that command but when I try to import them in Python 3.7.6 in terminal, I am getting an error like this:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ''
```

But when I try to import the modules again with Visual Studio in Python 3.7.5, I can import it.
So my question is how can I download pip packages for Python 3.7.6 and not for Python 3.7.5?
And my pip3 version shows like this:

```
pip3 -V

pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `virtualenv` ? You can specify which python version you actually want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the pip packaged by your distribution, it will be linked with the python version distributed by your distribution (version 3.7.5).

The better is to install both from apt, without install it manually :

```
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip
```

If you really need to install latest version manually (but I don't recommend it) , [pip is included](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) in the python you just installed manually. You can use it like this :

```
python -m pip install <Package_Name>
```

If you need to have several versions of python in your computer, you can use [virtualenv](https://linuxconfig.org/setting-up-the-python-virtualenv-development-environment-on-debian-linux)